# ASP .NET Local Deployment - Can't Access Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

I'm trying to deploy ASP.NET on local network from my desktop. 
I've completed all IIS steps, and the website is opened on the login page.
But every time I try to login I receive this error.

```
Server Error in '/MReserve' Application.

The network path was not found

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
```

This is my connection strings produced from the publish profile.

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|aspnet-MReserve-20150516063047.mdf; Initial Catalog=aspnet-MReserve-20150516063047;Integrated Security=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MReserve.Models.MReserveDB" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MReserveDB.mdf; Initial Catalog=MReserveDB; Integrated Security=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MReserve.Models.MReserveDB_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MReserveDB.mdf; Initial Catalog=MReserveDB; Integrated Security=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Kindly would you please help me in solving this issue. 
I've enables INBOUND rules of firewall for both: TCP/IP connections and World Wide Web.

Comment: what you mean exactly with 'deploy on local network'? you want to install it on a local server? or just make it accessible to the lan but residing on your pc? did you try to debug?

Comment: I'm trying to run the application through local network of nearly 50 desktops. 
I made a setup for service pack 1 and debug, that was the error message appearing now : 
" Additional information: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. "

Comment: Check the connection string in the web.config and check thet the user you set there has enough permission to create a database.

Comment: The problem was the database wasn't published on the server. 
After publishing it to local server on local network.
I can login with username and password on sql studio. 
But when it comes to running the website, after opening the login page, it fails to login. 
giving that error. 
{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}
However, when i tried to debug with connection string to database on the server side I was logged in normally with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by enabling these firewalls inbound rules:
1) SQL Port (1433) 
2) Web World Wide 
3) IIS Express (Local Port: 80)